# R count function

Tags: r, count, dplyr

I am using the *dplyr* package to count the frequency of values in one of my columns. I previously used the below code and it was working fine until today.

```
library(dplyr)

df = data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), Leaver = c("Leaver", "Leaver","Non-Leaver","Leaver","Non-Leaver","Leaver"), office = c(1,1,3,2,3,1))

count(df, "Leaver")
```

This returns the following:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 2
'"Leaver"'     n
<chr>      <int>
1 Leaver         6
```

And I want it to return:

```
Leaver        4
Non-Leaver    2
```

I was using this count function last week as written above and it used to output the desired result. However, when rerunning my code this week, after making some changes to other fields, it is now outputting the over total.

Why has this changed or how can I fix it?

Comment: Remove the quotes `count(df, Leaver)` and it should work as expected.  If you are using a quoted string then have to change it to symbol and evaluate i.e. `count(df, !! rlang::sym("Leaver"))`  or use the deprecated `count_(df, "Leaver")`

Comment: Why not `as.data.frame(table(df$Leaver))`? There are many advantages in using packages, namely `dplyr`, but in this case base R can do it in a simple way.

Comment: Thank you both.  @ akrun Would you have any idea why it worked fine last week with the quotes around it and suddenly changed? @ Rui Thanks I am pretty new to R and didn't know I could do it that way.

Comment: Did you update anything?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is already given [in the comments by *akrun*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688403/r-count-function#comment90338645_51688403), but I will answer in order to show that in this case base R performs better.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(microbenchmark)

mb <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  base = as.data.frame(table(df$Leaver)),
  dplyr = count(df, Leaver),
  times = 1e4
)

mb
#Unit: microseconds
# expr      min        lq      mean    median       uq       max    neval
# base  402.629  415.6465  458.6573  426.1225  456.041  10882.93    10000
#dplyr 1640.708 1685.2085 1855.7103 1711.7485 1756.767 197173.87    10000
```

Since a picture is worth one thousand words, package `microbenchmark` has a utility function to graph the results, an `autoplot` method, `autoplot.microbenchmark`, for objects returned by function `microbenchmark`.

```
autoplot(mb)
```

[image]

After *akrun*'s comment I have decided to test both ways with a larger dataframe.

The results now favour `dplyr`.

```
df2 = data.frame(Leaver = sample(c("Leaver","Non-Leaver"), 1e7, replace=TRUE))

mb2 <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  base = as.data.frame(table(df2$Leaver)),
  dplyr = count(df2, Leaver)
)

mb2
#Unit: milliseconds
# expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
# base 421.4232 661.3697 648.7873 669.2828 676.4261 860.5663   100
#dplyr 326.6446 367.7304 378.3681 372.8822 386.2788 569.0868   100


autoplot(mb2)
```

Comment: On such a tiny table, it's hard to believe anyone would mind an extra second... (surprised it's that much unless you're using a different table)? It would be better to benchmark with a larger table rather than repeat 1e4 times to illustrate the point, I think. Maybe like `DF = data.frame(x = sample(100, 1e7, replace=TRUE)); system.time(dres <- dplyr::count(DF, x)); system.time(bres <- as.data.frame(table(DF$x)))`